# How can I find which file or code affected to my code in html, css

Tags: php, css, html

I wanted to make my website and I wanted to add my page what I mad.
So I added some map code to custom page with
"display: inline-block;"
But if I start that page, It disappear like this picture.

```css
element.style {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 0px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 480px;
  display: none;
}
```

How can I find which code affected to my code?
Just tell me the way how can I find it.
I need skills plz

Comment: Do you know what `display: none;` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding an element can be done by setting the display property to "none" or the visibility property to "hidden". (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Try it without the display none:

```
element.style {
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
padding: 0px;
width: 800px;
height: 480px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following CSS `display: none;`

Comment: I'm using Wordpress theme, so there is a lot of CSS file with display: none; code. I don't know how can I find that code what effected on my code.